# Python - Get all the variable in template passed from views.py render() function

Tags: python, django, templates, view, render

Code in my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
def webapppage(request):
    parameter = {
    'key1':'hello',
    'key2':['hiiii','whats up','buddy']
    }
    return render(request, 'template2.html', parameter)
```

How can I get both {{key1}} and {{key2}} in one single variable like (parameter) in my template file?

Code inside template2.html

```
{% for c in parameter %}
    `{{c}}
{% endfor %}
```

I want output like

```
hello ['hiiii','whats up','buddy']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want that output just replace your template with:

```
{{parameter.key1}} {{parameter.key2}}
```

If you want to keep your template as it is then pass the context as a list like:

```
return render(request, 'questapp/template2.html', {'parameter': [v for v in 
               parameter.values()]})
```

If you want to pass a dictionary then you can try:

```
return render(request, 'questapp/template2.html', {'parameter': 
                                                  parameter})
```

and change your template:

```
{% for  c in parameter.values %}
    {{c}}
 {% endfor %}
```

Comment: I want variable (parameter) as it is in my template file. I am able to get the value of key1 and key2 by using {{key1}} {key2}} in my template file but I want a single variable that contains all the values (value of key1 + value of key2) that I had assigned in variable(parameter).

Comment: Thanks ....But I know about the way you mentioned above like making a dictionary and pass all the values at one of key of the dictionary. I want only one dictionary to be passed in the function with many key and values and I can get all of them in a single variable in my template file. I don't know wheather it is possible or not ?

Answer (score 0):

As I read your requirement, you want to pass one dictionary with many key and values.
We might do something like this.

In views.py

```
def webapppage(request):
    parameter = {
        'key1':'hello',
        'key2':['hiiii','whats up','buddy']
    }

    context = {
        "parameter" : parameter 
    } # The template will only contain one dictionary

    return render(request, 'template2.html', context=context)
```

In the template

```
{% for key, value in parameter.items %}
    {% if key == 'key1' %}
        {{ value }}
    {% else %}
        {% for name in value %}
            {{ name }}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Now the template will able to get all value in a single variable.